# Request payload size exceeds the limit: Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I get the above error when exporting forest change detection analysis from earth engine. The AOI is New South Wales, Australia, and my exporting code is as below;

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------
----------------------EXPORTING--------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------*/
//Exporting(to Drive)
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: ndviDifference,
  description: 'nsw2019', 
  folder: 'EAus', 
  fileNamePrefix: 'nsw2019', 
  region: AOI.geometry(), 
  scale: 10, 
  maxPixels: 1e10
  });
```

The error received is; **Request payload size exceeds the limit: 10485760 bytes.**